# i am having issues installing laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am having issues installing laravel. I have followed the first two methods, `(composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1") and (composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist)` on this [site](http://laravel.com/docs/installation) and they failed.
I guess upon looking through the forums i need to output my result for compose diag......

```
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking HTTP proxy: OK
Checking HTTP proxy support for request_fulluri: FAIL
Unable to assert the situation, maybe packagist.org is down (The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request))
Checking HTTPS proxy support for request_fulluri: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

1. I want to know why i cannot install laravel with these two methods.
2. I am using a proxy. Yes. But i don't know what reques_fulluri means and what it does.

Comment: It fails because you can't get the files. You can't get the files because you can't reach packagist.org. You can't reach packagist.org because your proxy can't see it. Solve for X.

Comment: i have also tried with sudo -E ....... but it fails to download. How do i go around the proxies. this is my error http://i.imgur.com/kyHYrX1.png